# Как сделать итерацию кортежа

Tags: python, sql, циклы

Пишу бот в телеграмме, который обращается с запросом в БД (postgres). Результат выдачи приходит в кортеже. Перед каждым элементом кортежа я прописываю в выдаче название этого элемента. Все получается, но только для первого кортежа, второго в результате нет.

```
def askFio(message):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    fio = message.text
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Спасибо, идет обработка запроса')
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test.test_1 WHERE value11 = '{}'".format(fio))
    for i in cursor:
        get_sql = i[0]
        get_sql1 = i[1]
        get_sql2 = i[2]
        get_sql4 = i[4]
        get_sql9 = i[9]
        get_sql10 = i[10]
        bot.send_message(chat_id, f'ИНН: {get_sql}' 
            f'\nНаименование ЮЛ: {get_sql1}' 
            f'\nДата регистрации ЮЛ: {get_sql2}'
            f'\nВид деятельности ЮЛ: {get_sql4}'
            f'\nЮридический адрес: {get_sql9}'
            f'\nРуководитель: {get_sql10}')

        connection.close()
```

Так как поиск по ФИО, следовательно может быть несколько компаний. Но выдает только одну(пример запроса напрямую к базе):

('ИНН', 'ООО "RIC COMPANY"', '03.06.2019', '46909', 'Оптовая торговля широким ассортиментом товаров без какой-либо конкретизации', None, '105', 'Малые предприятия (<= 5) (от 0 до 5 чел.)', '351013100', 'Юридический адрес', 'Иванов Иван Иванович')

('ИНН', 'ООО INT COMPANY', '20.06.2011', '46909', 'Оптовая торговля широким ассортиментом товаров без какой-либо конкретизации', None, '105', 'Малые предприятия (<= 5) (от 0 до 5 чел.)', '351013100', 'Юридический адрес', 'Иванов Иван Иванович')

Comment: может, connection.close() из цикла вынести

Comment: splash58, не помогло. Закомментировал закрытие соединения

Comment: `for i in cursor.execute(...`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, а при чём в вопросе метка [sql], какое отношение она имеет к задаче описанной в вопросе?